# Format of this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> (Thank you) (for something), (John).

Or

> (Thank you) (John) (for something).

The former sounds more suitable to be used in a normal conversation wheres the latter sounds more suitable to be used in a speech when thanking somebody publicly. Or both is fine to be used anywhere anytime?

Comment: Both are perfectly correct and likely to continue to be used.

Comment: If you see(?) a lot of native speakers producing something, then it is grammatical *by definition*. If "it's annoying me" is all you have going against it, then this is peeving disguised as a question which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both instances are correct and there's no difference in meaning.

> - Thank you for picking up the check, John.
> - Thank you, John, for picking up the check.

The former sounds more natural to me, but that's certainly not grounds for disregarding the validity of the latter.

Comment: The latter might come in handy when there's a whole crowd standing around you and you want to be specific right off the bat about whom you're thanking. (And of course you could even move the address to the very front.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt True. That's a good example because it incorporates an element of pragmatism (rather than merely personal preference) into the comparison. Your example is a case where I'd use the second version.